# When does std::atomic<> post-increment take place?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

I'm confused about how does the atomic post-increment actually work. For example

```
std::atomic<int> a = 1; // global
void func(int i) {
    std::cout << i;
}

// execute the following in two threads
func(a++);
```

I believe `a` finally becomes 3, but is it possible to see the output "11"? Is it safe to expect one of the two threads will definitely see `a` became 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lets look at how this work if `a` were not atomic:

1. Make a copy of `a`
2. Increment `a`
3. Pass the copy of `a` to func

In the atomic case, it is similar except that the copy/increment happens atomically.  The copy is still passed to func.

Since the increment/copy is atomic, the first thread to call `++` will increment it from 1 to 2, and pass 1 to func.  The second one will increment it from 2 to 3, and pass 2 to func.  Note, the order of the calls to func is not deterministic, but it should be called once with the value 1, and once with the value 2.

Post-increment `operator++` is [defined to be equivalent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) to `.fetch_add(1)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Even if `a` finally become 3, the "11" is still considered as a data race?

Comment: @YZ.learner: With your code change to func, it should never see `11`.  The increments should each call `fetch_add(1)`, which by default uses sequential consistency, which should result in it incrementing cleanly.  Now, you could easily see '21' or '12'.

Comment: Being seq_cst is irrelevant here; there's only one atomic object so even `a.fetch_add(1, relaxed)` would still guarantee that one increment sees `1`, the other sees `2`.  Since both `21` and `12` are possible with `seq_cst` (since the race to output via `std::cout` is separate), relaxing it to `relaxed` doesn't actually change anything.  Relaxed atomic RMWs are still atomic, just not ordered wrt. operations on *other* objects.